# What happens to the reputation points when stackoverflow user will deletes account or expires user

Tags: discussion

Suppose a Stack Overflow user has an account for a couple of years. They have thousands or tens of thousands of reputation points. Such a user deletes their account, or it accidentally expires, what will happen? Will Stack Overflow reward  that user in any way? Does Stack Overflow maintain a gallery of "legendary" users?

Comment: User accounts of active users don't "expire," accidentally or otherwise.

Comment: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: When a user deletes their account, the points are automatically transferred to Jon Skeet. Much like the film Highlander - there can only be one.

Comment: *When a user deletes their account, does SO reward that user?* No, because that user deleted their account, so there's no one to reward, and it's also not logical to reward someone for deleting their account. We don't offer a badge or other rewards to accounts that do not exist, and deleting your account makes it non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of what you want to figure out is covered [in this Meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it).

To paraphrase, all the reputation that the user had is lost.  Their account is deleted; it's essentially the same as not having an account.  They're *gone*, and the only thing that the user gets is a (short-lasting) memory from those of us who may have interacted with them before.

The tricky part comes in when they've *given* lots of reputation out.

If the user has sufficiently low votes when they are deleted, then a user who was voted on by the now deleted user will see "User was removed" and a chunk of reputation removed.  One generally sees this with spam accounts or accounts that partake in voting fraud.  Because those votes really shouldn't have been, it's no big deal.

If you have a user that had lots of upvotes, then you run into a serious issue; because that user has contributed so many votes to Stack Overflow, deleting their account and *all* of the reputation that they awarded through votes or bounties(?) would have ***major*** repercussions throughout the system.  So, those deletions are done very carefully as to allow a long time participant delete their account without it causing major damage to the system.